# Grails Possible to use javascript with <g:if>?

Tags: grails

Is it possible to use the state of a javascript global variable in the "test=" of a  tag? If so how would I access that variable since ${} is usually to evaluate variable sent from the Controllers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using GSP tags from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998006/using-gsp-tags-from-javascript)

Comment: GSP tags are evaluated on the server and JavaScript is evaluated on the client, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a jQuery function in conjunction with JSON data returned from your controller. You may be able to accomplish what I think you need.